# Why is Royal Slider adding height and width of 0px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have royal slider set up on a site im working on. Its set up on the home page and on my products page where I have a section that displays multiple royal sliders in different divs that the user can toggle between.

The first of the sliders in the products page I have managed to set up and it displays correctly. However when I get to the 2nd royal slider in the same section I can see that the height and width are both set to 0px and I cannot figure out why? Ive looked on the support forum for royalslider but I cant find anything that helps me understand why this is happening.

Here is the HTML for my 2nd slider:

```
    <div class="container">
                <div class="row toggle-prod ps2">
                    <div class="span7">
                        <div class="royalSlider-prod2 rsDefault">
                            <img class="rsImg" src="/IMG-1.jpg" width="670" height="660"/>
<img class="rsImg" src="/IMG-2.jpg" width="670" height="660"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span5">
                        <p>PhoneShield 2 (PS2)</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the JS for the slider:

```
$(".royalSlider-prod2").royalSlider({
        keyboardNavEnabled: true,
        autoScaleSlider: true,
        slidesSpacing: 0,
        imageScalePadding: 0,
        loop: true,
        navigateByClick: false,
        arrowsNav: false,
        autoScaleSliderWidth: 670,
        autoScaleSliderHeight: 660,
        controlsInside: false,
        autoPlay: {
            enabled: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            delay: 5000
        }
    });
```

The JS for the first slider on this page is exactly the same which is why I dont understand why the height and width arent being picked up for the second slider.

Comment: I found this suggestion [link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/entp-tender-production/assets/0ad026b8a4b95640cd59b892b670a29005d009d8/Full_Width_Slider___RoyalSlider_Example.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISVUXXOK32ATONEQ&Expires=1392645713&Signature=sv5Y1uP5Czf33OYePCdqMcV4k1A%3D) from the maker of royalslider but I dont want to add css in that way for every breakpoint because I managed to get the first slider working without having to add any styles and it picks up the options from my JS file.

Comment: Create a fiddle demo or paste your link. Otherwise its hard to assume what is wrong.

Comment: I cant paste A link because Im working on a file on my local machine. Not sure how to create a fiddle either. I inspected element in chrome to find that my div .royalSlider-prod2 has height set to 0px. When I inspect element for .royalSlider-prod1 height is set to 660px. I dont understand why .royalSlider-prod2 has a height of 0 when I have specified it in the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more than one slider on the same page and setting display none to the others (which is what I had to do because I didn't want them all to be visible at the same time) causes the other sliders to get a height and width of 0px. I didn't realise this for a while. In the end I used bootstraps carousel slider which works perfectly and there are no conflicts no matter how many sliders I have on the page.